# How do I find the value of a certain cell in a table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have a set of rows like below

```
[u'215/', u'05-Mar-2019 04:00  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'216/', u'05-Mar-2019 05:00  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'217/', u'05-Mar-2019 05:59  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'218/', u'05-Mar-2019 06:59  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'219/', u'05-Mar-2019 08:02  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'220/', u'05-Mar-2019 08:57  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'221/', u'05-Mar-2019 10:00  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'222/', u'05-Mar-2019 10:58  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
[u'223/', u'05-Mar-2019 12:01  ', u'  - ', u'&nbsp;']
```

I need to get the digits (eg : 215) from each row. My code is as below.

```
    build_url = self.previous_build_url
    val = ""
    page = urllib2.urlopen(build_url)
    page_data = page.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page_data)
    for node in soup.findAll('tr'):
        row = node.findAll(text=True)
        print row[0][1]
```

This is throwing error as     print row[0][1]
IndexError: list index out of range. How do I fetch the value of a cell in a row?

Comment: I think `row[0]` should give the digits(like 215). Can you `print row[0]` and show what you get?

Comment: I tried it. Still getting     print row[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then, can you show the output for `print row`? Please add this info to the question.

Comment: print row gives exactly the above set of rows which i have given

Comment: @Cathy12341 see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some of the rows are empty...

Try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page_data)
for node in soup.findAll('tr'):
    row = node.findAll(text=True)
    if row:
        print row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not print `node[0]`? I think your problem is that `row = node.findAll(text=True)` is coming up empty so your index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really well formed, but since you're new around here (:|)...
You don't really need BeautifulSoup for this. Try:

```
  data = """[your data above]"""
  array = data.split("\n")
  for word in array:
      my_list = word.split(',')
      print(my_list[0].replace("[u'","").replace("/'",""))
```

Output:

```
  215
  216
  217
  218
  219
  220
  221
  222
  223
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use a first-child selector

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page_data)
items = [item.text for item in soup.select("tr td:first-child")]
```